# How to remove or delete app which is online on DocuSign [docusignapi]

Tags: docusignapi

I created an app on docusign (Apps and Keys) from my DocuSign developer account, then put it to production on another DocuSign account.

I am now looking at how to remove this application from production (take it offline) and how to remove it from the developer account and/or the production account.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are the owner of the IK in the developer account, you should be able to remove it yourself, by using this menu on the right:
[image]

In production you cannot do this, you will have to contact customer support for this.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

The app I want to remove is in production. So I have to contact customer service to be able to delete it.
It's a bit weird I think though.

Any idea why they didn't put the option directly?

Comment: This is a good question Rodolphe and I will take this up with the product team. I think there may be some concerns about ensuring that when you delete a production app it's done with the approval of the owner of this app (there may be more than one person that have access) but I'm not sure that's the only reason.

Comment: I understand the idea. But it's only deletion that is not allowed once the application is in production. App information (user application, service Integration, additional settings, ..) can be edited by anyone who has access to the account. 
I hope a balance will be found, such as sending a verification code (as is done at login) or something else. Thanks Inbar.